# How to convert a list of array to Spark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Suppose I have a list:

`x = [[1,10],[2,14],[3,17]]`

I want to convert `x` to a Spark dataframe with two columns `id` (1,2,3) and `value` (10,14,17).

How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x = [[1,10],[2,14],[3,17]]
df = sc.parallelize(x).toDF(['ID','VALUE'])
df.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can create it directly using SparkSession-

```
x = [[1,10],[2,14],[3,17]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=x, schema = ["id","value"])
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```