# combine model.clusterCenters and model.transfrom of k-means in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means

Update: I want to achieve this in scala spark, not pyspark, so the answer suggested in this [Convert KMeans “centers” output to PySpark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56835496/convert-kmeans-centres-output-to-pyspark-dataframe)
 question doesn't work(no tolist method)

I have trained a k-means model. With "model.clusterCenters", I can get the vector of each cluster center point, the data type is Array[Vector], with "model.transform", I can get the prediction index for each sample vector as a new column.

So suppose if the training dataset dataframe is like:

```
+------------+--------------------+
|rest column |            features|
+------------+--------------------|
|     1646177|[231.8,232.1,233....|       
|     1646177|[232.2,234.2,234....|        
|     1646178|[241.1,234.1,244....|
|     ...    |...                 |
-----------------------------------
```

after model.transform(), I get the following:

```
+------------+--------------------+----------+
|rest column |            features|prediction|
+------------+--------------------+----------+
|     1646177|[231.8,232.1,233....|        01|
|     1646177|[232.2,234.2,234....|        01|
|     1646178|[232.1,234.1,234....|        02|
|     ...    |...                 |       ...|
----------------------------------------------
```

after "model.clusterCenters", i can get an array of vector like following:

```
[230.99036144578324,231.08433734939757,231.3566265060241...]
[160.6,159.9,177.2...]
[69.3,70.1,70.6...]
...
```

where the number of cluster centers correspond to the unique values(01,02...) in the "prediction" column of the above dataframe generated by model.transform

What I want to achieve is to concatenate the both,the expected result should be like following:

```
+------------+--------------------+----------+---------------+
|rest column |            features|prediction|cluster centers| 
+------------+--------------------+----------+---------------+
|     1646177|[231.8,232.1,233....|        01|[123,456,789...|
|     1646177|[232.2,234.2,234....|        01|[123,456,789...|
|     1646178|[232.1,234.1,234....|        02|[232,243,223...|
|     ...    |...                 |       ...|...            |
-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!